# Turn off loading animation when encountering error on form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a simple email form that turns on a loading animation (jQuery) when submit is clicked:

```
onClick="$('.loader').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

A jQuery form handler sends the ajax data to a PHP mail file for processing and error checking that turns the animation off:

```
if(trim($name) == 'Name *') {
exit('<div class="error_message">You must enter your name.</div>
<style type="text/css">.loader { visibility: hidden !important; }</style>');
```

Works a treat but only on the first form error. Any subsequent errors will not turn the loader on/off.

Don't understand why if the PHP script changes the visibility property to hidden why the property can't be turned back to visible since each time you hit the submit button the loader should be visible! I admit to being a PHP noob so please don't hammer my score.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could gather all the errors first, end then, in the end merge them all, then exit it:

```
$errors = array(); // an array that will hold the errors
// errors, push them inside the container
if(trim($name) == 'Name *') $errors[] = '<div class="error_message">You must enter your name.</div>';
if(trim($email) == 'Email something') $errors[] = '<div class="error_message">You must enter your email.</div>';

if(!empty($errors)) { // if there are errors
    // add the style on the first position
    array_unshift($errors, '<style type="text/css">.loader { visibility: hidden !important; }</style>');
    echo implode("\n", $errors); // join them all
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I like your suggestion and will give it a try. Sequential If Else statements to validate my data works better for my puny PHP coding skills :)

Comment: @hillcreative sure man i hope this turns out well. that email was just an example, just change it the way you wanted it to fit into your code base.

Comment: Gave the collection array a shot but still have the problem of not being able to turn the loader back on for final submit (after error corrections) My goal here is to have a loader animation running on a validated form while the mail is sent via PHP.

Comment: @hillcreative im assuming this is an ajax operation right? have you tried setting the visibility after the DOM elements have been loaded properly? most likely bind the visibility to visible, after its been loaded, not right after it was clicked.

Comment: Not sure I understand as the click triggers the jQuery Ajax document that changes the css property not the DOM loading as in $(document ).ready Thanks again for hanging in there with me!

Comment: @hillcreative have you tried, after triggering the css visibility on the success block instead?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ghost using the loader visibility property on the success function on the jQuery AJAX call worked. I had it in the PHP server side which would not update the page.

```
$.post(action, {

        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        phone: $('#phone').val(),
        comments: $('#comments').val()

    },

        function(data){

            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
            $('#message').fadeIn(200);
            $('.hide').hide(0);
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');

            if (data != '') {
                $('.loader').css('visibility','hidden'); //hide the loader animation on error
}
```